# JSF Primefaces: How to change the input value on focus event?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to change the value of the same input when the onfocus event trigger but the value of the input doesn't change.

```
<dcisc:textfield id="folioExam" autocomplete="off" value="#{customerInfo.folioExam}" editable="true" mandatory="NON_MANDATORY">
    <p:ajax event="inputFocus" listener="#{customerInfo.unMaskFolioExam}" />
</dcisc:textfield>


public void unMaskFolioExam(){
     // Do some process
    folioExam = unmaskedValue;
}
```

I want to change the value of the input when the user try to edit the input.

Comment: are you missing `update="@this"` on your `p:ajax` event to re-render the input?

Comment: @Melloware I added update="@this" but it doesn't allow me to write